# Какой вариант правильный? Постановка запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение

1. Поднимайся, боец, за тобой пришли.
2. Поднимайся боец, за тобой пришли.

Мне кажется верным второй вариант, но правильно ли это? Слово "боец" должно выделяться запятыми как обращение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, ***боец*** в этом предложении является обращением и выделяется с обеих сторон. Его легко можно изъять из предложения.

*Поднимайся, боец, за тобой пришли.*

[**§ 27. Обращения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126) (Розенталь)

> Обращение вместе со всеми относящимися к нему словами **выделяется (в середине предложения)** или отделяется (в начале либо в конце предложения) запятыми, если произносится без восклицательной интонации.

*Послушай, двадцать пятый, что ты здесь делаешь?*

*Пойте, горы, степи и поля!* (Сурк.)

*Что делаешь, милая?* (Островский)

*Поезжайте, душенька, Илья Ильич!* (Гончаров)

*Шуми, шуми, послушное ветрило,

 Волнуйся подо мной, угрюмый океан.* (Пушкин)